# ArrayList Relation in java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

so i still learn about arraylist stuff in java, 
lets say i have two arraylist

```
name = [John,Mark,David,Luke,Dame]
thingsTheyHave = [ball,racquet,golfStick,laptop,personalComputer,shoes,shirt,chair,table,phone]
```

my question, how to create these 2 arraylist become something like this :

```
john : Ball , golfStick 
mark : Laptop,personalComputer
david : racquet,shoes
luke : shirt, chair
dame  : table,phone
```

what method do i have to use ? thanks in advance !

Comment: You don't get your expected output, because there is no relational information between people in the first list and items in the second list.  Is this a homework question, and, if so, can you include more information?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen its not a homework question , it just come up my mind, to create an arraylist relation between one arraylist into another since i new into programming stuff. hmmm the relational information between people and item is the people have certain items. and im confused how to create the arraylist connected like this. thats make me ask question

Comment: For your desired output Hashmap is best suitable, where name will be your key and list of things as values. You can learn about hashmap [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-hashmap)

Comment: Your expected output implies some sort of map, nothing at all wrong with that, but you would need to know how to related a person with his various items.  I'm not seeing a way to do this right now.

Comment: @Tejendra for the hasman , is it posible like put random items into one arraylist ? or do i have to create each arrraylist item for each value then iterate it and put it into hashmap?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen oh i see , actually its just a question that i come up with, and im confused  how to create an arraylist with relation (the example above might be wrong, because it didnt provide more information).

Comment: @JakiroDragon You have to create separate arraylist for each values of containing item.

Comment: @Tejendra i see , thanks for ur response sir ! i think i got the idea

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks for responding this thread sir !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use `java.util.Map`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> equipmentMap = new HashMap();
equipmentMap.put("John", Arrays.asList("Ball", "golfStick"));
```

And then you can get things that John have like this:

```
equipmentMap.get("John");
```